# How to provide array to a super class if I need initialize it in a child?

Tags: java, inheritance

There is the problem: I have different 2d arrays for each of 7 classes, for example:

```
int array = {
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 1},
    {1, 0, 1}
};
```

All 7 classes extends one super class, so I wanted to make a getter of this array in super class, and provide this array into super's constructor, i.e.

```
class Super {
        public Super(int[][] array) {
            this.array = array;
        }

        public getArray() {
            return array;
        }
    }


class Sub {
        int[][] array = {
            {1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1},
            {1, 0, 1}
        };

        public Sub() {
            super(array);
        }
    }
```

But it can't be done, because array at the moment of passing it to a super's constructor is not initialized. Writing 7 getters and 7 setters seems to be bad solution. Also initializing it into Sub constructor will be awful, as I can't use array initialization syntax and will set value of each cell of array.

Are there other ways to do general getter inside of Super?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there's no need to have the same field `array` in each subclass.

It would be sufficient to have this field along with appropriate constructor and getter in the super class, and then call this constructor from subclasses:

```java
public class Super {
    private int[][] array;

    public Super(int[][] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }


     public int[][] getArray() { return array; }
}
```

```java
public class Sub1 extends Super {
     public Sub1() {
         super(new int[][] {
             {1, 2, 3, 4} // sub1 data
         });
     }
}

public class Sub2 extends Super {
     public Sub2() {
         super(new int[][] {
             {1, 0, 0}, // sub2 data
             {0, 1, 1}
         });
     }
}
```

etc.
Simple test:

```java
Super[] supers = { new Sub1(), new Sub2() };
for (Super s : supers) {
    System.out.println(s.getClass().getSimpleName() + " -> " + Arrays.deepToString(s.getArray()));
}
```

Output

```
Sub1 -> [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
Sub2 -> [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot I can initialize everything when I pass it somewhere... Thank you very much, it's completly solves the problem